# Emitter current doubt

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

In my semiconductor lesson about npn transistor I found emitter current (Ie)=base current(Ib)+collector current(Ic).Now for practical purpose we can get the values of different current using micro and millammeters.My doubt is is the current  flowing in the interior of n-region of emmitter same as that flowing in connecting wires as measured by microammeter?I know current in emmitter connecting wire is due to flow of electrons only while in the interior of n-region due to electrons + holes.Now will same net charge flow in any cross-section of emitter as that in the cross-section of connecting wires?

Comment: Where else could the current go?

Comment: @Farcher is there any restriction that prevents it from changing?

Comment: This would mean that the device was storing charge. I doing so its potential would have to rise.  Does this happen?